# jquery add backslash to string

Tags: jquery

I am creating a input text box using jquery:

```
<input type='text' name='" + key + "-" + taskArray[i] + "' id='" + key + "-" + taskArray[i] + "' class='vendorDropdown' value='" + value.baseOrSchedStartList[i] + "' />
```

when `Anthony's Excavating & Grading` it returns `Anthony` how do I get to display the full text, here is what it looks like in html:

```
<input type="text" name="ANC0002-Water &amp; Sewer Installed" id="ANC0002-Water &amp; Sewer Installed" class="vendorDropdown ui-autocomplete-input" value="Anthony" s="" excavating="" &="" grading'="" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: you are doing it wrong your name and id of textbox should not content space or any special characters. where name can be same but id must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace single quote( ' ) with double quote( " ), it will solve your issue.

```
<input type="text" name="' + key + '-' + taskArray[i] + '" id="' + key + '-' + taskArray[i] + '" class="vendorDropdown" value="' + value.baseOrSchedStartList[i] + '" />
```

Answer (score 1):

try this , use value=\""+mvalue+"\"

```
<input type='text' name='" + key + "-" + taskArray[i] + "' id='" + key + "-" + taskArray[i] + "' class='vendorDropdown' value=\"" + value.baseOrSchedStartList[i] +"\" />
```

in this way you can use special characters and spaces also